# Reference Types in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

How reference types are stored on heap in .NET? (means in which form)
If in application have 2 objects with same name how those objects will stored on heap?

Comment: Huh? Please clarify. At the moment, this question makes no sens.

Answer (score 5):

**Objects don't have names.** The references (on the stack or as fields inside objects) have names and they refer to the objects. But 1 object can have more than 1 reference pointing to it.

Answer (score 3):

[How Reference and Value types are stored in memory ?](http://blogs.msdn.com/saurabhv/archive/2004/11/26/270684.aspx)

Comment: Ick - the fact that it propagates the "value types are stored on the stack" myth in big bold letters puts me off instantly.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't mattery how they are stored; how they are stored is an implementation detail. You should be concerned with the observable characteristics of types, not implementation details. Further reading:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only relevant concern about how objects are stored, in *most* run-times, is that objects are streams of bytes, which might be contigious, and the primary knowledge about the objects is in code that manipulate references to it.